# How to fit featured image in to div with overflow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with my thumbnails on http://mixchuti.cz/category/obrazky/

I have a div over the img width size (250x250px) and different sizes of featured images. Overflow is fine by that but i need to set image height or width to 100% of div depends on higher parameter.

For more information what I'm trying, here's my working code for that:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.wp-post-image').ready(function() {

if ($(this).css('height') > $(this).css('width')) {
    $(this).css('width','100%')
} else {
    $(this).css('height','100%')
}
});
});
</script>
```

and fronted is classic WP thumbnail:

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):the_post_thumbnail('featured_post_image'); endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, you want the image to fit the size of the div?

Comment: yes, but just the higher dimension. Rest of image will not show because of overflow.

Comment: $(this).css('width') returns the width of the image, checkout jquery doc for more information http://api.jquery.com/css/
so you don't need any variables

Comment: I would suspect the failure has to do with your selector $('.obimg img'). You should test if the function is called at all. E.g. by putting console.log("do it"); in front of your if-statement

Comment: I changed code (and edited this post) but I'm not sure where to put consoloe log. Can you copy the line above and over with this line?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the other dimension as auto?

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.wp-post-image').ready(function() {

if ($(this).css('width') > $(this).css('height')) {
    $(this).css('width','100%');
    $(this).css('height','auto');
} else {
    $(this).css('height','100%');
    $(this).css('width','auto');
}
});
});
</script>
```

I added a couple of semi-colons, not sure if you left them out on purpose here.

Comment: I guess its a working cod, but nothing happened after pasting it to my site. I'm not sure how i can try if image call function right.

Comment: What about setting height as a variable and width as another (var imgheight = $('.wp-post-image').height(); etc. Compare height and width. Also, is the class ('.wp-post-image') definitely correct? Also maybe run this on document.ready or set a function name and call it?

Comment: I'm sorry for the multiple comments, but did you by any chance try using CSS alone by giving the images (.wp-post-image) the styles of (max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;), the bigger one will fill an axis and the other one will be smaller. Am I completely off here? I think this might solve your issue.

Comment: I tried document.ready and nothing changes. Also I changed width > height to height > width cause actually the lower dimension has to be 100% and higher dimension is auto so the div dont show whole image. So thats for your second comment, i got my "if" wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of us would agree that this needs to be fixed directly from the CSS script not using jQuery. To make these changes in CSS see example below.

```
<style type="text/css">
.thumbnail{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbnail img {
    height: auto ; 
    width: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://yourdomain.com/dir/imagename.png"  alt="" height="127" width="300">
</div>
```

[image: Preview of code]